# python: Calculating seconds from a datetime string with extra characters

Tags: python, datetime

I want to create a new column which contains seconds since 1970 for each row for the following input file:

```
timestamp, air_temp, rh, pressure, dir, spd
2016-11-30T00:00:00Z,-36.50,56.00,624.60,269.00,5.80
2016-11-30T01:00:00Z,-35.70,55.80,624.70,265.00,5.90
2016-11-30T02:00:00Z,-34.80,56.00,625.00,266.00,6.30
```

The first column represents the timestamp but it contains extra characters 'T' and 'Z'. My current code looks like this:

```
i = 0
ip_file.readline()
for line in ip_file:

    line = line.strip()

    year[i] = int(line[0:4])
    month[i] = int(line[5:7])
    day[i] = int(line[8:10])
    hour[i] = int(line[11:13])

    time[i] = (datetime(year[i],month[i],day[i],hour[i])-datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
    i += 1
```

This returns me what I want but it takes long time if input file is big. If the timestamp didn't had those extra characters, I would have directly used it instead of calculating year, month, day and hour. Is there a better way? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using string slice. Why not **split the string by comma**? And use **strptime** method in datetime module to convert string datetime to datetime object.

**Example**:

```
import datetime

with open(path, "r") as infile:
    for i in infile.readlines()[1:]:
        dVal = i.strip().split(",")[0]
        print (datetime.datetime.strptime(dVal, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')-datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

**Output:**

```
1480464000.0
1480467600.0
1480471200.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Input:

```
import datetime as dt

line = '2016-11-30T00:00:00Z,-36.50,56.00,624.60,269.00,5.80'

# We know the datetime data is always 20 characters long
line_dt_str = line[:20]
line_secs_since_epoch = dt.datetime.strptime(line_dt_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').timestamp()
print(line_secs_since_epoch)
```

Output:

```
1480482000.0
```

Note that there is a difference between calling `.timestamp()` and subtracting your datetime from the 1970 epoch. This comes from how these two methods handle (or don't handle) daylight savings time. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602652/difference-between-evaluating-timestamp-and-total-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first splitting your line in file on `,` and casting it to `datetime` object

```
>>> import datetime

>>> line = '2016-11-30T00:00:00Z,-36.50,56.00,624.60,269.00,5.80'
>>> t = datetime.strptime(line.split(',')[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

To convert to seconds you can simply use:

```
>>> int(t.strftime("%s"))
>>> 1480435200
```